# Deleting empty columns using vba

Tags: vba

```
With WS.UsedRange
        For iCol = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(iCol)) = 1 Then 
            .Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next
    End With
```

WorksheetFunction.CountA will count the number of non-Empty columns if I am not wrong. WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(iCol)) = 1 will give the result True if the columns are not empty since the value is 1.

But, I am trying to delete the empty columns and this code is doing it. But not sure how this code works.

This code works for deleting empty columns. But, this is not clear.
Can someone clear it for me?

Comment: Why Use 1 Here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as shown can't work since there's a missing `End If` or `.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete` must immediately follow `Then` in the same line

assuming your actual code does work, then you are right in how `WorksheetFunction.CountA` works, and this must mean that your columns are considered to be empty if they have only one value, possibly some header

of course this also means that the header MUST be in the wanted row

While if you want to delete *completely* empty columns you have to code

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(icol)) = 0 Then .Columns(icol).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: How can I delete empty columns then?

Comment: see bottom of edited answer. if it solved your question please consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: The above one which is "If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(icol)) = 0 Then .Columns(icol).EntireColumn.Delete" is not working. It is not deleting the empty columns. But when we make it "1" instead of "0", it will work. That's where the code is confusing.

Comment: then what you consider "empty" columns are not really empty, but they contain one element (possibly some header). difficult to help you further without seeing your actual data